# railsのsystem testでheadless_chromeを使いたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

現在、Ubuntuのdocker上にrails 5.1.7の開発環境を構築しています。
そしてその上でjsを含んだViewテストをする為に、system testのテスト環境を構築しているのですが、インストールと設定が上手くいかずに困っています。

まずエラー内容を説明させていただきます。

```sh
rspec spec/views/hoge/index_spec.rb
```

このコマンドを実行すると、

```
          ArgumentError:
            unknown driver: :headless_chrome
```

というエラーが出ます。

私はネットの記事で調べheadless_chromeでテストする為にrails_helper.rbに対して以下の行を追加しました。

```rb
  config.before(:each) do |example|
    if example.metadata[:type] == :system
      driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
    end
  end
```

またdocker上のubuntuにchromedriverをインストールしました。

```sh
# chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864})
```

どの様にすればこのエラーを解決できるでしょうか？
ご回答いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドライバの指定がrailsのバージョンで異なるようです。
以下のようにするとどうでしょうか？

```rb
      driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
```

参考
https://qiita.com/jnchito/items/c7e6e7abf83598a6516d#%E3%83%98%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AEchrome%E3%81%A7%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらの方法でエラーなしで動作する様になりました。ありがとうございました。